# Selecting a particular tab on pressing back button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I know using setSelectedNavigationItem(index) method we can select a particular ActionBar tab.
But is it possible to set it by pressing back button on another activity?(i.e. when I press back button on another activity and move to my current activity holding tabs, is it  possible that a different tab is selected ?)
I posted a similar question earlier but it didn't work.
Please help!!

Comment: yes.The back button pressed on another activity

Comment: I just posted solution for your problem.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send the tab index you want to select as a parameter on your intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent("TabActivity");
i.putExtra("tab_index", 1);//you can put 1,2 or the index you want to
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The main avtivity extends FragmentActivity.How should I catch it there?

Comment: Putting the getIntent().. in onCreate() throws an error!!
Unable to start activityComponentInfo

Answer (score 0):

Override the BACK pressed just enough to set the Tab index to `wanted_position`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(wanted_position);
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```